# Is there a name for this "inner product" on projective space?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, terminology, inner-product

$\newcommand{\proj}{\mathbb{P}}\newcommand{\complex}{\mathbb{C}}\newcommand{\ip}[2]{\langle #1 , #2\rangle}\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert #1 \rvert}$There is a natural bijection $\phi: \proj(\complex^n)\rightarrow S(\complex^n)/U(1)$, where $S(\complex^n$) is the unit sphere of $\complex^n$ with respect to the Hermitian inner product, and $U(1)=S(\complex)$ (i.e, $\phi$ identifies projective space with the unit sphere modulo complex phase). We can therefore define a map
$$
\abs{\ip{\cdot}{\cdot}}^2: \proj(\complex^n) \times \proj(\complex^n) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+
$$
by $\abs{\ip{[u]}{[v]}}^2=\abs{\ip{\tilde{u}}{\tilde{v}}}^2$, where $\tilde{u}, \tilde{v}$ are any representatives of the equivalence class of $\phi[u], \phi[v]$, and the bracket $\ip{\cdot}{\cdot}$ on the righthand side is the standard Hermitian inner product on $\complex^n$.

Does this map have a name? Does it fit into some well-known category of maps on projective space?

Comment: For $n=1$ this is a map $S^2\times S^2\to{\mathbb R}^+$. The only candidate that comes to mind is cosine square of the angle, is it this?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე $S^1$ surely if we are looking at the unit "sphere" in ${\mathbb C}$?

Comment: @YemonChoi Sorry I meant $n=2$. What confused me is the nonstandard notation. The $\mathbb P(\mathbb C^n)$ of the OP is what one usually denotes by $\mathbb C\mathbb P^{n-1}$. For $n=1$ it is a single point (I think).

Comment: MathJax note:  unlike in ordinary TeX, blank lines, or even spaces, after command definitions won't be ignored, so you have to butt up the beginning of the question directly against the `$` ending the definitions.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: Isn't this sort of inner product-ish used in quantum mechanics for computing probabilities?

Comment: @LSpice Yes! This is the context in which it has come up for me.

Comment: Keeping with the QM theme: one can identify a projective state $[u]$ with a rank one density matrix $|u\rangle \langle u|$, and then your "inner product" is the square root of the Hilbert-Schmidt inner product between the two associated density matrices.

Comment: Is it related to the Fubini-Study metric? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%E2%80%93Study_metric